# Is the Weak Event Pattern weak for both source and listener?

Tags: c#, weak-events

Reading about the [Weak Event Patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) it is clear to me that it allows for garbage collecting the `listener` when it is not longer referenced but is the reciprocal true also ? Meaning does this pattern allows for garbage collecting the `source` when it is no longer referenced (except via attached weak `listener`) ?

**Why am I asking this**: I want to implement a CopyOnWrite pattern between some "source" and "listener" where the second one is just a subset of the first one. So I need to "detach" whenever one write to the source/listener or when the source disappears (because no need to keep a large amount of data while only a subset is still referenced). So I need very loose coupling between the source and the listener (i.e. letting them both be garbage collected whenever one or the other is no longer strongly referenced).

Comment: This pattern solves a problem where a source keeps a listener object alive longer that it's natural lifetime. Note that *the opposite problem doesn't occur*, the source can always be collected whether or not it still has listeners, if it is otherwise no longer reachable.

Comment: Ok thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever ... Reading documentation confused me, yes source event is classic `Event` as usual, so no need to worry in fact. This question can be closed :)